# Emacs: how to find a variable by its value?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have some value and know that some Emacs variable holds it. How to find, which variable has this value in it? The value can be a symbol, integer or string, and the variable may hold the value itself, but a list which contains a value.

Example. A variable `default-directory` contains string `"/var/www/"`. I have that string, but i suddenly forgot the variable's name. How do i search through variables and find that `default-directory` contains that string?

Is there some builtin function for that, or the only solution is custom elisp snippet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-value` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^"/var/www/"$` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

The required command is `apropos-value`.